# Deleting a collections of VBA buttons

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using the following script to produce buttons in excel, the range is just where I'd like it to be placed.

```
Sub CreateAddButton(rng As Range)
    Dim btn As Button
    With Worksheets("User")
        Set btn = .Buttons.Add(rng.Left, rng.Top, rng.width, rng.Height)
        With btn
           .name = "Add"
           .Caption = "Add Column"
           .OnAction = "CreateVariable"
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Only problem is, I'd like a method which can delete all the buttons produced by this method? I want to steer away from global variables if possible. Any help would be gratefully received.
James

Comment: You could tag all buttons by using a specific prefix or suffix in the name: then you could loop through all the buttons on the sheet and delete any where the name contained that prefix/suffix.

Comment: I'd have to you some sort of golbal variable to do that, and I'm trying to get rid of all global variables, as they lose their value if there's an error in excel.

Comment: Why would you need a global variable to do that? You don't! (Unless you count your whole Excel instance as a global variable...) See @brettdj's implementation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*I'd suggest Tim's method using a specific name - which does't need a global variable. For example you could add a
"_||ForDeletion"* suffix to each button name and then look for it on a delete routine

```
 .Name = "Add_||ForDeletion"
```

A `Forms` button does provide another alternative though (no pun intended), you can store a text sting in the `AlternativeText` under "Properties" then "Web" and use this as an identifier for a delete routine.

The delete routine at bottom works backwards to avoid errors when looping through a range

[image]

```
Sub TesMe()
    Call CreateAddButton([a2])
End Sub

Sub CreateAddButton(rng As Range)
    Dim btn As Button
    With Worksheets("User")
        Set btn = .Buttons.Add(rng.Left, rng.Top, rng.Width, rng.Height)
        With btn
            .Name = "Add"
            .Caption = "Add Column"
            .OnAction = "CreateVariable"
            .ShapeRange.AlternativeText = "MyCollection"
        End With
    End With
End Sub


Sub GetMyButtons()
    Dim btns As Object
    Dim lngRow As Long
    Set btns = Sheets("User").Buttons
    For lngRow = btns.Count To 1 Step -1
        If btns(lngRow).ShapeRange.AlternativeText = "MyCollection" Then
            MsgBox "Found one", vbCritical
            btns(lngRow).Delete
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Buttons in VBA are in the Shapes collection.  You can use:

```
Sub deleteButtons()
Dim btn As Shape

For Each btn In ActiveSheet.Shapes
    If btn.AutoShapeType = msoShapeStyleMixed Then btn.Delete
Next

End Sub
```

msoShapeStyleMixed seems to be the type for all Form and ActiveX controls.

Comment: That would be great, but there are some buttons I need to keep on the page. I think the only way I can identify the buttons I want to delete is by either the name or the caption properties.