# How do I delete all buttons on a worksheet?

Tags: excel, vba

I've got a bit of code that creates a Save button on a worksheet (held in the `wsReport` variable), but it doesn't remove previous buttons. Over time, they tend to build up. Is there any way to do something like this?

```
wsReport.Buttons.All.Delete
```

(Not right, obviously, but gives an idea of what I'm looking for.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deleting a collections of VBA buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8898976/deleting-a-collections-of-vba-buttons)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

See code below :)

```
Sub RemoveButtons()
Dim i As Integer
    If ActiveSheet.ProtectContents = True Then
        MsgBox "The Current Workbook or the Worksheets which it contains are protected." & vbLf & "                          Please resolve these issues and try again."
    End If

    On Error Resume Next
        ActiveSheet.Buttons.Delete
End Sub
```

Source:
http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/609668-delete-all-buttons-sheet-visual-basic-applications.html

or could you use code below:
(Buttons in VBA are in the Shapes collection).

```
Sub DelButtons()
Dim btn As Shape

For Each btn In ActiveSheet.Shapes
    If btn.AutoShapeType = msoShapeStyleMixed Then btn.Delete
Next

End Sub
```

source:
[Deleting a collections of VBA buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8898976/deleting-a-collections-of-vba-buttons)

Comment: `Activesheet.Buttons.Delete` worked very nicely all on its own - many thanks!

Answer (score 3):

See the code below:

```
Sub DeleteAllShapes() 

    ActiveSheet.Shapes.SelectAll

    Selection.Delete

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

If somebody found this question, but needs to delete **only one button**, this helped me:

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes("my_button_name").Delete
```

Answer (score 0):

There's an easier method that doesn't use VB:

1. Click the Developer tab
2. Click Design Mode
3. Click on any button in the worksheet
4. Press Ctrl + A to select all buttons in the worksheet
5. Press Delete

Comment: You need to activate Developer Tab first: [Display the Developer tab in the toolbar](https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/questions/developer_tab2013.php)